# How to style a readonly select based on option's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```js
 $("select").change(function(){

    if((this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=="Non")) {
    
       $(this).val("Non").css("background-color", "red");
        }
    else if((this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=="Oui")) {
    
          $(this).val("Oui").parent().hide();
    
    
    
        }
     }
    
       
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Lit et couvre lit</span>
<select >
 <optgroup label="Lit et couvre lit">
  <option name="Oui" value="Oui" selected="selected">Oui</option>
  <option name="Non" value="Non">Non</option>
  </optgroup>
 </select>
```

code

it works in this case but my problem is that I have a readonly select like this

```html
<select  class="readonly" id="PST_LIT" title="Lit et couvre lit">
  <optgroup label="Lit et couvre lit"><option name="Oui" value="Oui" selected="selected">Oui</option><option name="Non" value="Non" disabled="disabled">Non</option></optgroup></select>
```

I didn't know how to set the code to deal with a "readonly" select to get the same resultes as shown in the first code snippet

ANY HELP PLEASE?

Comment: Your second example cannot be updated as the only other choice is disabled, so where's the issue?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my problem that I want to hide the "Oui" option and color the "Non" option as shown in the first one

Comment: My point is that 'Non' cannot be selected, so the problem is moot

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if fact I have formulaire in witch I have a group of select options when I submit it I got a formulaire where the previous not selected value is disabled

Comment: @Soulef what is formulaire?

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman sorry I mean A form